# Ionization isomerism in coordination compounds

Tags: coordination-compounds

Ionization isomerism is defined as complexes which have same empirical formula but ionize to different ions in solution.

Consider the complex $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4Cl2]I2}$. The other possible ionization isomers are:
$\ce{[Pt(NH3)4I2]Cl2}$ and $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4ICl]ICl}$.

But I have not come across the complexes similar to the last one with two different anions outside the coordination sphere.
So, do these sort of complexes **exist**?

Moreover, what can be the IUPAC name for this compound?

tetraamminechloridoiodoplatinum(IV) chlorineiodine seems wrong.

Comment: -iodido-, -chloride iodide.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be -

**tetraamminechloridoiodoplatinum(IV) chloride iodide.**

The rules of the naming of counter ions are pretty much the same as in general Inorganic Chemistry. I do know of a compound AgClI - named as Silver chloride iodide. So, I think the counter ions here - chloride and iodide should be named as by the nomenclature rules of anions i.e with an -ide suffix and alphabetically if there is the presence of more than one anion

Proof of Reference - [Silver chloride iodide (NCBI PubChem)](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Silver-chloride-iodide)

**EDIT**: My teacher did give an example of it being a valid complex. I think it is not generally stated in the preliminary books of this topic to avoid confusion among students.I imagine it would be present in some more in-depth books of this topic.

Comment: OK... but my original query was... Is this complex possible? Seems affirmative to me. So why there are no such examples in the books?

Comment: @Apurvium I think its a matter of the level of the books. The book I mentioned was of STD 12 level-which is the first time Coordination compound is taught.I think such examples would be found in some higher level books.